# Java EE Module Dependencies page in Eclipse missing projects

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, dependencies

We're developing a web application using Tomcat and a number of other libraries, and we're having issues using the "Java EE Module Dependencies" page in Eclipse to assign dependencies to be placed in the lib/ directory of the webapp. (See screenshot)

The issue we're having is that while most of our projects show up as available dependencies, a few are missing. We've done our research, and on some machines all of our projects appear properly, but not on others. Is there any rhyme or reason to the missing projects?
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Eclipse <3.6 because the "Java EE Modules" page was removed in favor of a "Module Assembly."  Can you reproduce this with Eclipse 3.6 as well?

Comment: I will download a copy of Eclipse 3.6 and test, but we check out our Eclipse installations from a shared location. Upgrading everyone to 3.6 would take a bit of time, and we'd like to find a resolution for 3.5, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a WAG, but can you try adding a "Utility Module" facet to the projects you want to add as a Java EE Module Dependency?

[image]

And then see whether those projects are available to be added as Java EE dependencies.

Comment: Sounds promising, but when I select that option, I receive the error message: "Utility Module requires Java 1.3 or newer", which we definitely have. :)

Comment: That's really odd.  So you have a check next o "Java" and it's selected to 1.6/6 or whatever?  I'm not sure if these issues are related, but your projects' Eclipse files seem to be screwed up somehow.  I would recommend re-creating the projects from scratch, if possible.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I didn't see that Java was also in the list, I thought that the error indicated I didn't have Java installed on my machine. Selecting both the "Utility Module" and "Java" items caused the missing project to appear in the Java EE Module list. Thanks!!